Passing boolean value parameters to Bicep from a devops pipeline yaml
Thanks to this post, I know how to pass parameters from my yml pipeline through the AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment task to my bicep IaC script. However, my argument arrives as string, even though I specified them in my pipeline.yml as boolean.
This leads to the error 'The provided value for the template parameter 'my_parameter_inside' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Boolean', but received a value of type 'String'.
My pipeline.yml
parameters:
- name: my_parameter
  displayName: Deploy spark pools
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    csmFile: $(bicep_file_name)
    csmParametersFile: $(bicep_parameter_file_name)
    ...
    overrideParameters: -my_parameter_inside ${{ parameters.my_parameter }}

The parameter inside my bicep file:
@description('Enable/Disable something')
param my_parameter_inside bool = true

How can I ensure that the value is passed as a boolean?

I found a bug issue in GitHub in which someone found a workaround for the problem  - we have to pass it in lowercase to be recognized as boolean since it would otherwise be passed as False instead of false and Bicep doesn't accept it.
-> ${{ lower(parameters.my_parameter) }}
Working pipeline.yml
parameters:
- name: my_parameter
  displayName: Deploy spark pools
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    csmFile: $(bicep_file_name)
    csmParametersFile: $(bicep_parameter_file_name)
    ...
    overrideParameters: -my_parameter_inside ${{ lower(parameters.my_parameter) }}


A little tricky here. I have just test using ${{ lower(parameters.my_parameter) }} it also works. But what I want to say is parameters boolean always be treated as string in later inline script or AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3  so first need to convert the true or false string to bool True or False then use it.

Thanks for sharing the solution. I notice there is a suggestion ticket to ask not to capitalize the boolean parameter. You can submit a vote and add some comments to increase the priority.
